# SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running error while shutting down

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am able to start server any number of times but when i am trying to shut it down it is showing error as below. Can anyone please tell me how to resolve.

```
localhost:8080 is displaying message as successfully installed. Congratulations!

Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33

Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33

Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/temp

Using JRE_HOME:        /

Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer

SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.

SEVERE: Catalina.stop: 

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)

at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)

at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)

at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)

at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:450)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)

at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:400)

at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:487)


**Log file**

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_71-b15

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.731 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.733 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.733 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/conf/logging.properties

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.733 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.733 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/endorsed

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.734 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.734 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.734 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/temp

12-Apr-2016 12:01:16.734 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib

12-Apr-2016 12:01:17.280 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

12-Apr-2016 12:01:17.363 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read

12-Apr-2016 12:01:17.367 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

12-Apr-2016 12:01:17.372 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read

12-Apr-2016 12:01:17.373 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 2123 ms

12-Apr-2016 12:01:17.444 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina

12-Apr-2016 12:01:17.445 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.33

12-Apr-2016 12:01:17.511 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/ROOT

12-Apr-2016 12:01:18.243 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/ROOT has finished in 720 ms

12-Apr-2016 12:01:18.244 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/docs

12-Apr-2016 12:01:18.352 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/docs has finished in 108 ms

12-Apr-2016 12:01:18.354 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/examples

12-Apr-2016 12:01:18.995 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/examples has finished in 641 ms

12-Apr-2016 12:01:18.996 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/host-manager

12-Apr-2016 12:01:19.065 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/host-manager has finished in 69 ms

12-Apr-2016 12:01:19.066 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/manager

12-Apr-2016 12:01:19.123 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/share/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps/manager has finished in 57 ms

12-Apr-2016 12:01:19.137 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

12-Apr-2016 12:01:19.144 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

12-Apr-2016 12:01:19.145 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1772 ms

12-Apr-2016 12:03:46.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.

12-Apr-2016 12:03:46.071 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

12-Apr-2016 12:03:46.124 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

12-Apr-2016 12:03:46.175 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina

12-Apr-2016 12:03:46.272 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

12-Apr-2016 12:03:46.288 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

12-Apr-2016 12:03:46.382 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

12-Apr-2016 12:03:46.393 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]

12-Apr-2016 12:30:40.202 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.33

12-Apr-2016 12:30:40.206 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Mar 18 2016 20:31:49 UTC

12-Apr-2016 12:30:40.207 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.33.0

12-Apr-2016 12:30:40.207 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux

12-Apr-2016 12:30:40.207 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64

12-Apr-2016 12:30:40.207 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64

12-Apr-2016 12:30:40.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.71-2.b15.el7_2.x86_64/jre
```

Comment: Please quote or indent logs for better reading :)

Comment: @Patrizio Bertoni...I have given log file details. Could you pls help me now

Comment: You've already stopped it. The log file proves it.

Comment: Reading your question, it seems you're starting as many instances of tomcat as you can... Are them running on different ports?

Answer (score 17):

I just answered this question under another question.

I solved it today,it maybe a bug with jdk-1.8.x.

For example,my jdk path is **"/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144"**.

```
cd /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/lib/security/
```

find the file which named **"java.security"**,

```
vi java.security
```

find **"securerandom.source=file:/dev/random"**.

Modify **"securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom "**.

Or add `-Dsecurerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom` in Tomcat's CATALINA_OPTS.

Then,go to the Tomcat/bin directory, execute `./start.sh` and `./shutdown.sh`,find that everything is all right.

This helps in a specific scenario of an incomplete Tomcat start up resulting from some operation blocking in '/dev/random' reads in the event of low system entropy.  The Tomcat shutdown port is only listening after a full start up, so if a start attempt hangs in a '/dev/random' read or due to any other issue, the shutdown port is not listening and a shutdown attempt relying on it fails with the connection refused error.  If start up hangs in '/dev/random', then the urandom change addresses this as /dev/urandom never blocks and hangs waiting for system entropy.

A CATALINA_PID may be set to shutdown Tomcat using a pid file and OS signal without issue in this event instead of the shutdown port.

Comment: Almost spent a day to figure out this. Finally tried this, it worked out. Not sure why this happened. As far as i could say, i have not done much except resizing my disk in GCP. Anyhow it solved the agony. Thanks

Comment: how did you figure this out!?

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that the server port not changed after the server started!

Changing the sever port of a running server could make it unable to shutdown with error message like the following:

`06-Feb-2018 10:17:10.682 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer Could not contact [localhost:[8005]]. Tomcat may not be running.
06-Feb-2018 10:17:10.693 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer Catalina.stop:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Answer (score 3):

it's because you have startup tomcat on port and you trying to shutdown on  an another port, solution is to change default tomcat shutdown port which is 8085, so if you have started your tomcat server on port 8080, go on you /tomcat/server.xml file and change this one

```
<Server port="8085" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

to

```
<Server port="8080" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Cordially

Comment: Changing the port will not matter. Port 8005 is use to shutdown the server and 8080 is use to start it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in jdk 1.8.x - here is how to fix it:

- In Windows Explorer, navigate to JRE --> lib -->security
- Open file `java.security`
- find "`securerandom.source=file:/dev/random`" in this file
- replace it with: "`securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom`"

Then, run the following commands from the `bin` folder of tomcat:

a. To start your server:

`startup.bat` or `catalina.bat start`

b. To stop your server:

`shutdown.bat` or `catalina.bat stop`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong - port 8080 is the port your application/tomcat will serve. If you change it, it will not matter for the problem as the special port 8005 is used for shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `java.security` doesn't solve my issue, which in this case killing by PID will help. In Linux to archive the following objective you need to do:

1. lsof -i:8005(Port number)
2. kill PID

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this problem is that killing active process. Mainly problem caused from active two server. As a solution you can kill this process then restart server, and everything is okay.

```
$ ps -fu

$ kill PID_of_target_process
```

[Look this link!](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31849616)

Answer (score 0):

Changing shutdown port to 8080 not helps.Without killing a process not able to start tomcat server.
default setting

changed like below but not works.

to kill a proces find process ID for port 8080
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin>netstat -ano | findstr 8080
TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6076

then kill it , I am using windows machine.

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin>taskkill /PID 6076 /F
SUCCESS: The process with PID 6076 has been terminated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).